# Calculate covariance in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, covariance

I have a `cv::Mat` like this:

```
500.0   350.2
500.5   355.8
498.7   352.0
............
```

And I need calculate the covariance. The result would be something like:

```
0.8633    1.2167
1.2167    8.1733
```

---

Of course, the function I need is **calcCovarMatrix**.... BUT if I execute this code:

```
cv::Mat a = (cv::Mat_<double>(3, 2) << 500.0, 350.2, 500.5, 355.8, 498.7, 352.0);
cv::Mat mu, new_covs;
cv::calcCovarMatrix(a, new_covs, mu, CV_COVAR_NORMAL | CV_COVAR_COLS);
```

The result is an incomprehensible 3x3 matrix...

```
new_covs=
[11220.02, 10838.03, 10987.83;
  10838.03, 10469.045, 10613.745;
  10987.83, 10613.745, 10760.445]
```

I hope you can help me with my problem!

Comment: I'm guessing [calcCovarMatrix](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#calccovarmatrix) is going to be helpful.

Comment: I have edited the question with more information.

Comment: Your samples are the **rows** of the input, right? So why are you telling the function that it is the columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation you need the flag "CV_COVAR_SCALE" to obtain a scaled covariance.

The mean is actually provided already scaled, so no need to scale it further.

The right solution is then:

```
cv::Mat a = (cv::Mat_<double>(3, 2) << 500.0, 350.2, 500.5, 355.8, 498.7, 352.0);
cv::Mat mean, covs;
cv::calcCovarMatrix(a, covs, mean, CV_COVAR_NORMAL | CV_COVAR_ROWS | CV_COVAR_SCALE);
```

Comment: CV_COVAR_SCALE normalizes the covariance by `1/nsamples`. While in Matlab, the normalization factor is `1/(nsamples-1)`. So the result will be different from that of Matlab.

Answer (score 4):

I found the correct way to do it:

```
cv::Mat a = (cv::Mat_<double>(3, 2) << 500.0, 350.2, 500.5, 355.8, 498.7, 352.0);
cv::Mat mean, covs;
cv::calcCovarMatrix(a, covs, mean, CV_COVAR_NORMAL | CV_COVAR_ROWS);
mean=mean/a.rows;
```

I hope it would be helpfully to someone!!!

Greetings!!